# org-mode: I can recalculate all tables, or realign, but not both

Tags: org-mode

I've got a dynamic block in org-mode (e.g. a clocktable) and I want to update it on save. To do this, I have written the following function (which I'm calling in a `before-save-buffer` hook):

```
(defun my/org-update-and-realign ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-dblocks 'org-update-dblock)
  (org-table-map-tables 'org-table-align))
```

(I need to do realignment because otherwise tables come up [garbled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNmJe.png).)

However, it doesn't wok. I get “Mapping tables: done” in the Messages buffer, but the table isn't realigned. Bafflingly, if I add `(redisplay)`, it does work:

```
(defun my/org-update-and-realign ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-dblocks 'org-update-dblock)
  (redisplay)
  (org-table-map-tables 'org-table-align))
```

So, I've got two questions:

1. How come?
2. Can I do it without `(redisplay)`? The `(redisplay)` forces a blink, which I don't want.